# valuelistenablebuilder for ValueNotifier<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>

Tags: flutter, dart

I came to know that we cannot **refresh the state** of the class using **valuestatebuilder**. This is very unfortunate for me. Because after weeks of hardwork  i am finally on the verge to complete my first flutter app/

The problem: I want to update the state of the mainclass. Map is stored in another. I have tried both: **setstate and valuenotifier** but all in vain. Can someone please tell me how to overcome this problem and how to use listenablebuilder to update the main class? thanks.

Example Code:

```
// class where the map<> is located.
// totalBill is the variable i want to use the value of in the next class
    var totalBill = ValueNotifier({});
    Map billl = {};
    int temp = 0;
    
    class ReusableCard extends StatefulWidget {
      ReusableCard({
        required this.itemName .....
...
...
// down in the class:
return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {

        setState(() {
          totalBill.value[widget.itemName] = temp;
        });
      },
```

then in the next class:

```
ValueListenableBuilder<Map>(
// totalBill is being borrowed from the above example / class 
                    valueListenable: totalBill,
                    builder: (context, val, _) {
                      //print(val);
                      //print(itemsInList);

                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(val.toString()),
.... 
...
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: This question has started to gain much attention now. 
-> My advice after using flutter for a while: Use GETx or any other state management tool. It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ValueNotifier* only notifies when the value is changed. In case of Map, value is reference. Which won't be changed if the value inside it is changed.

### Fix

Change the `onTap` function to the following

```dart
onTap((){

  totalBill.value[widget.itemName] = temp; // or change the value to whatever you want   
  totalBill.notifyListeners() // this notifies to all the listeners. 

});
```

**For more : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29958**

Answer (score 1):

`ValueNotifier` notifies **only** when its `value` is **changed**. In your example you do not change the `value` (i.e. `Map`) but you **must**.

The correct code is:

```dart
setState(() {
  totalBill.value = {widget.itemName: temp};
});
```