# Update a variable inside stateful class from another widget / class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am realtively new to flutter. HOW TO UPDATE a private variable inside a stateteful flutter widget from another class.

- I KNOW ONE WAY IS TO DECLARE IT GLOBALLY but THIS WILL CHANGE MANY THINGS. FOR EXAMPLE: This card is like a button. There are many buttons generated from this class. If I make **_temp** a global variable; i will lose the sole purpose i.e it being unique for all buttons, all categories, all foods.
- another way can be to create a method but i am not sure how t aces it from outside the widget? e.g:

  void reset() {
  _temp = 0;
  }

Please see the code to understand the problem:

```
class ReusableCard extends StatefulWidget {
  ReusableCard({

    required this.itemName,
  });

  final String? itemName;

  @override
  State<ReusableCard> createState() => _ReusableCardState();
}

class _ReusableCardState extends State<ReusableCard> {

 // HOW TO UPDATE THIS int _temp (BELOW) FROM ANOTHER CLASS?
 // I KNOW I CAN DECLARE IT GLOBALLY but THIS WILL CHANGE MANY THINGS.
 //  FOR EXAMPLE: This card is like abutton. There are many buttons generated from this class. If I make _temp a global variable; i will lose the sole purpose i.e it being unique for all buttons, all categories, all foods.


  int _temp = 0;
       
  @override
  Widget build(BuildCon .......
```

---

### **UPDATE**

Class where i am trying to reset temp i.e calling: "reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;":

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'buttonn.dart';
    import 'cardbutton.dart';
    
    var foodCategory = ValueNotifier(0);
    
    class Sidebar extends StatefulWidget {
      const Sidebar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<Sidebar> createState() => _SidebarState();
    }
    
    class _SidebarState extends State<Sidebar> {
      final GlobalKey<ReusableCardState> reusableCardKey = GlobalKey();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
//Buttonn basically is skeleton for elevated button.
            Buttonn(
              col: Colors.lightBlue.shade400,
              tex: 'Parathas',
              fixedsize: const Size(15, 180),
//buttonFunc is basically (){} of elevated button.
              buttonFunc: () {
                setState(() {
                  foodCategory.value = 0;
                  reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Buttonn(
              col: Colors.lightBlue.shade400,
              tex: 'Chai',
              fixedsize: const Size(15, 180),
              buttonFunc: () {
                
                setState(() {
                  foodCategory.value = 1;
    reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;
                  print(reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp);
                });
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Buttonn(
              col: Colors.lightBlue.shade400,
              tex: 'Others',
              fixedsize: const Size(15, 180),
              buttonFunc: () {
                foodCategory.value = 2;
    
                reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;
                print(reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp);
              },
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
            Buttonn(
              col: Colors.lightBlue.shade400,
              tex: 'pending',
              fixedsize: const Size(15, 50),
              buttonFunc: () {
                foodCategory.value = 3;
                reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by the following steps:

1. Make `_ReusableCardState` and `_temp` not private (i.e remove the underscore)
2. Make `ReusableCard` constructor takes an optional Key and calls its super constructor with this key. like this `ReusableCard({Key? key, required this.itemName}) : super(key: key);`
3. Define a key with the state like this `final GlobalKey<ReusableCardState> reusableCardKey = GlobalKey();`  in the class that calls `ReusableCard`
4. Pass this key to the `ReusableCard` like this `ReusableCard(key: reusableCardKey, itemName: "First Item")`
5. Now you can use this key (`reusableCardKey`) to modify `temp` through `reusableCardKey.currentState.temp = 28;`

Comment: Dear Omar, thanks for your time. I have done as you said. I have editted reusable class constructor to: ReusableCard({
    Key? key,
    this.colour = Colors.teal,
    this.price = 0,
    this.imageName = '',
    this.i = 0,
    this.itemName = '',
  }) : super(key: key);       so nothing is required in to call the constructor now.

Comment: than in the other class (happened to be: sidebar) inside _SidebarState , i am doing  
    setState(() {
              foodCategory.value = 1; ReusableCard(key: reusableCardKey);
              reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0;
              print(reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp);
            });   // print returns null. It is not working

Comment: The reusable card is not a part of the widget try, thus it will return null. Why are you calling the class in the setState function. You should place it in the widget tree

Comment: my bad; i have placed it in the right position. About "" reusableCardKey.currentState?.temp = 0; "". It is still not changing the value :(

Comment: can you add the _SidebarState code?

Comment: yes, i have updated my question with the Sidebar code int it after (UPDATE).  "Buttonn" simply helps desiging the button.

Comment: Bro, you are not using the key. so of course it will return null.
you should have the ReusableCard in the column for example and pass it the key
i.e inside the column add

ReusableCard(key: reusableCardKey, //any other params)

only then, calling reusableCardKey.currentState won't return null

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help dear Omar:) Can you please also take a look to another problem i am facing for a while now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70440608/valuelistenablebuilder-for-valuenotifiermapdynamic-dynamic